# Which unicode code can be used safely as reserved value?

Tags: swift, unicode, noncharacter

**Background**

I am writing a DFA based regex parser, for performance reasons, I need to use a dictionary `[Unicode.Scalar : State]` to map the next states. Now I need a bunch of special unicode values to represent special character expressions like `.`, `\w`, `\d`...

**My Question**

Which of the unicode values are safe to use for this purpose?

I was using `U+0000` for `.`, but I need more now. I checked the unicode documentation, the [Noncharacters](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#noncharacters) seems promising, but in swift, those are considered invalid unicode. For example, the following code gives me a compiler error `Invalid unicode scalar`.

```
let c = "\u{FDD0}"
```

Comment: Is it a regex parser or does it convert regular expressions to DFAs? Representing `\w` as a codepoint is silly anyway ­– what happens when you get to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`? Couldn’t represent every possible character class as a distinct codepoint even if you wanted to (but you wouldn’t want to because it’d be bad design).

Comment: @Ryan It is a DFA based regex parser, which means it converts regex syntax into DFA, and use that to do matching work. Range expression will be enumerated, i.e. `[0-9]` -> `[0123456789]`. My original implementation was to pre-process `\w` into `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`, but that means I will have to generate 64 states in my DFA for `\w`. Which leads me to the idea of using a codepoint (only 1 state) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `Unicode.Scalar`, nothing. `Unicode.Scalar` is designed to represent all valid characters in Unicode, including *not-assigned-yet* code points. So, it cannot represent *noncharacters* nor dangling surrogates (`"\u{DC00}"` also causes error).

And in Swift, `String` can contain all valid `Unicode.Scalar`s including `U+0000`. For example `"\u{0000}"` (== `"\0"`) is a valid String and its length (`count`) is 1. With using `U+0000` as a meta-character, your code would not work with valid Swift Strings.

---

Consider using `[UInt32: State]` instead of `[Unicode.Scalar: State]`. Unicode uses only `0x0000...0x10FFFF` (including noncharacters), so using values greater than `0x10FFFF` is *safe* (in your meaning).

Also getting `value` property of `Unicode.Scalar` takes very small cost and its cost can be ignored in optimized code. I'm not sure using `Dictionary` is really a good way to handle your requirements, but `[UInt32: State]` would be as efficient as `[Unicode.Scalar: State]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know. Thanks. BTW, what do you think is a better solution than `Dictionary` for my scenario?

Comment: @dawnstar, that depends on your implementation details. _Not sure_ does not mean _I have a better idea_. Hope you can find the best way. (It may be the Dictionary you described.) Good luck.